# Create a text file based on the folder and the file name

Tags: c#

```
I have 10 folders (C:\Import)
Folder1
Folder2
.
.
Folder10
```

Each folder have some .txt and .html files.

```
Let me take example of Folder1 having 3 documents 

file.txt 
file2.html
file3.txt 

files in it.
```

I need script to read the folder and create a txt file in below format.

Folder name 'separator' file name without extension 'separator' filename with extension

```
So output text file should be :

Folder1:file:file.txt
Folder1:file2:file2.html
Folder1:file3:file3.txt
```

and Move html, txt files and newly create text file too C:\Output.

This has to be repeated for all the 10 folders and all the corresponding files and created text file should be dropped to same C:\Output

Tried below :

1:

```
  foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Import\\", "*.html", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
    }
```

2:

```
 public static List<string> AllFilesInFolder(string folder)
        {
            var result = new List<string>();

            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
            {
                result.Add(f);
            }

            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
            {
                result.AddRange(AllFilesInFolder(d));
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Your code does not attempt to create any file. Look up the documentation for the `File.Create` method. It will help you creating the file. (Pay attention to File.Create's return value! Don't let the returned FileStream dangle, but rather your code should immediatly dispose/close it) To properly build the file path string required for `File.Create`, look at the documentation for the `System.IO.Path` class. It has several (static) methods that can help you building the correct file path string...

Comment: I might perhaps misunderstood your question somewhat. If you want to create a text file that contains a list of files, you can simply take the result of `Directory.GetFiles` and write it into a text file using the `File.WriteAllLines` method. If you want/need to process the file paths in _Directory.GetFiles_'s result collection, you can do so "on the fly" by using Linq's [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) method...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to write PowerShell script. The file manipulation is much easier in powershell, and you can always use .NET libriaries.

Please, take a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-files-and-folders?view=powershell-6), it's Microsoft doc about "Working with Files and Folders" using PowerShell.

But if you don't want to use PowerShell, you can do something like that:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("APP START");

        string inputDirectory = @"C:\Import\";
        string outputDirectory = @"C:\Output\";

        FileStream stream = File.Create(outputDirectory + "report.txt");

        string [] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(inputDirectory);

        foreach(String path in folders)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path.Replace(inputDirectory, outputDirectory)); 
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

            foreach (String file in files)
            {
                String record = ConvertPathToReportFormat(file);
                stream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(record), 0, record.Length);
                File.Copy(file, file.Replace(inputDirectory, outputDirectory));
            }
        }
        stream.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static String ConvertPathToReportFormat(string path)
    {
        string [] splitedPath = path.Split('\\');
        string[] splitedName = splitedPath[splitedPath.Length - 1].Split('.');

        String folder = splitedPath[splitedPath.Length - 2];
        String name = splitedName[0];
        String extension = splitedName[1];

        return String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}.{3}\n", folder, name, name, extension);
    }
}
}
```

This little program copy files from one directory to another, and generates report file (report.txt) in following format:

```
Folder1:File:File.html
Folder1:File:File.txt
Folder1:File2:File2.html
Folder1:File2:File2.txt
Folder1:File3:File3.html
Folder1:File3:File3.txt
```

Comment: @grav Sorry, I wanted to propose the best solution for specified problem. I updated my post. If still doesn't meet community requirements please delete it.

Comment: I reverted my comment and DV.  Thank you for following community guidelines @TheHunterPL